# How to add GPS data to audio files

Tags: audio

I want to geotag my audio files, but unfortunatly exiftool doesn't manage geotags for audio files.

I'm on linux, and I need a command line solution.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Not all audio file formats can save arbitrary metadata along with the file, but some do. WAV and MP3 are able to do that.

Now, I don't think that there is an audio file format which specifies a specific metadata name for GPS information and I don't know any app which would make use of such information to e.g. display a world map of your audio files.

That said, you can still save that information for yourself.

In [Audacity](https://www.audacity.de/), export the audio file as WAV or MP3. After the file name dialog, there's a dialog for metadata. In this dialog, click the "Add" button. You could e.g. create two entries, one for latitude and one for longitude, like so:

[image: Audacity metadata dialog]

In the screenshot, it says "whatever". Since there are more than 30 different ways of specifying a place on earth, I don't know what you want to enter there. Maybe you even want to add another field "GPS format" where you describe which data format you have used for the location.

A common format is certainly DMS, short for degree, minutes, seconds. You could e.g. specify 48°23'45.2" N or something.

Now, Audacity is not a command line tool. But [id3edit](https://github.com/rstemmer/id3edit) has similar capabilities for the ID3 tags of MP3. I haven't tried this personally, but the principle should be the same: you can add whatever metadata you like and the data will simply be text.